# An invisible traveller

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Maybe not a typical riddle, but here it is:

> I can travel from there to here by disappearing, but I can also travel from here to there by appearing.

What am I?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think the answer is

> The letter 't'

Because

> The words *here* and *there* differ by the letter 't' which either appears or disappears depending on which direction you go.

Comment: Because of the [tag:lateral-thinking] tag, this seems off. If we ignore that tag, this might be the right answer, congrats.

Comment: @Orphevs do you mean that it would be tagged [tag:wordplay], rather?  Well, I think it almost fits:  we expect disappearing and appearing at “here” and “there” to describe places, not something parallel — okay, so maybe [tag:parallel-thinking] more than [tag:lateral-thinking] …

Comment: @can-ned_food [tag:wordplay]:"A form of wit in which the used words become the main subject of the work, primarily for the purpose of intended effect or amusement.". [tag:lateral-thinking]:"A puzzle solved through an indirect and creative approach, using reasoning that is not immediately obvious and involving ideas that may not be obtainable only using logic.". Compare this question to [the lateral-thinking Q with the most votes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/a-double-agent-with-a-conundrum), and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Orphevs Yes, I know [tag:wordplay] — that's what my (admittedly only) puzzle posted was. :-)  Also, I read the tag summary of lateral-thinking prior to posting my comment, and I think I have a decent enough experience with it from Mindtrap and such, so I'm not sure what your point is; you need to explain it a bit more thoroughly, I'm afraid.  Maybe in chat?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's

> the Sun?

What is that which can travel from there to here by disappearing

> From our point of view, it goes from West to East by disappearing

but it has that special ability to travel from here to there appearing.

> From our point of view, it goes from East to West in plain sight

Comment: Can it also apply for zbba(rot13)?

Comment: Actually I started my answer with it. It probably applies to [nal fngryyvgr, angheny be abg](http://decode.org/?q=nal+fngryyvgr%2C+angheny+be+abg)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is

> Your own shadow.

Because

> It travels from there to here shortening its length and eventually disappearing.

And

> It travels from here to there appearing and subsequently increasing its length.

Answer (score 5):

My initial thought is

> Time

Because

> Time always seems to disappear when you need it

and

> There often seems to be a extra Time appearing when you are waiting around for something

Overall this makes:

> A Time traveler

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a decent answer, congrats on your first points. I see you have your 1st [badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges). you can get another by filling out your **[profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50617/marka?tab=profile)** and taking the **[tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's

> the Moon

because

> At one time it appears in a place and then due to its rotation it disappears and re-appears the next night.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is

> Rain

Disappears

> Evaporates

Appears

> In the form of rain

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a

> Photon

I can travel from there to here by disappearing, but I can also travel from there to here by appearing.

> It sounds like this is describing quantum entanglement, where a particle will exist simultaneously in both locations until observed. When you observe one particle, the other paired particle's spin will be determined based on that observation. The reverse is also true.

Answer (score 3):

This is my second approach. My previous answer pointed at something about we cannot say is invisible at all (as title suggests).

The better match is:

> Lower air pressure or low tide.

It is invisible because:

> Air is almost transparent. Although you can observe low tide living seaside but obviously you cannot see it, when you travel by ship.

It travels from there to here by disappearing:

> When air/water flows towards us, the lower pressure/tide disappears.

It travels from here to there by appearing:

> Opposite by analogy. :)

Comment: Damn, my answer is perhaps a bit more general version of this and I was writing it while you posted this answer. Oh well :/. I'll leave it there anyway, but if one of us is correct, you were first :P.

Comment: @Netzia Thanks, but I would perceive it as separate answer anyway, because stepping up into abstraction you might loose some properties. For instance: optical invisibility of the change or direction of flow of the medium :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> remoteness/distance itself?

I can travel from there to here by disappearing

> what was "there" would be "here" if the distance separating them vanishes

I can also travel from here to there by appearing.

> and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> airplane, because it disappears form the source airport after it takes off and appears on the destination airport after landing.

Comment: [ :-( ]  I don't think so:  per this answer, it first disappears then appears regardless of whether it goes from here–to–there or from there–to–here.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt this is what you had in mind, but something that behaves like this is

> A local change of a variable or a quantity in a system that tends to a global equilibrium.
>  In a physical system this could be e.g. pressure or temperature. If for some reason there appears a local change in, say, pressure (positive or negative), the change "travels" from here to there, i.e. the magnitude of the local difference in pressure decreases where it appeared and the magnitude of the pressure difference increases everywhere else, as the system tends to a new equilibrium.

Thinking about it the other way around,

> if the "original" change suddenly disappeared (i.e. the reverse happens) the change would "travel" from there to here as the system again tends to the "original" equilibrium.

As an example:

> For some reason a local pocket of overpressure appears: the system tends to a new equilibrium by distributing the pressure evenly, thus introducing overpressure (relative to the "original" state) everywhere else. Then at the same location a pocket of underpressure of equal magnitude to the earlier change is formed (meaning the overpressure "disappears" locally): the system tends to the original equilibrium by redistributing the pressure and thus the overpressure travels from everywhere else to "here".

Answer (score 1):

Answer

> Water my dudes. It goes from here (ground) to there (sky) by evaporation (disappearing). Then, it goes from there to here by appearing (rain).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68011/40789