# Internship Available!* - Figure out what you're being asked to do before you sign up

Tags: story

Sine waves bound in rectangles shaped into prisms. Mass increases, position changes twice, and mass decreases. The prisms become rectangles and are either discarded or stored for later use. *If that sounds exciting to you, you may have an exciting future in our field!* We need as many able-bodied candidates as possible to help with our project starting ASAP!

Due to lack of funding to actually pay a skilled team, we offer these fantastic incentives instead! How would you like some soggy old gramineaeze? Perhaps acidified coagulation and bio-viscera upon heavily triticumized water? Imagine what you could do with all of that! Sign up today to start this **FANTASTIC ADVENTURE!**

**YOUR FUTURE IS WAITING! CORPORATIONS DON'T UNDERSTAND THAT ALL CAPS IS BAD. JOIN US!**

**Company is not responsible for death or injury caused by crushing or falling.*

What are you being asked to do and how are they paying you?

Comment: Must have solid Windows NT, Java, C++, COBOL, Unix, VAX, z-Series and iOS.

Comment: I figured out the pay fairly quickly (I've worked for less), but the job itself is getting me.

Comment: The pay is meant to be easier to figure out, because it's a clue for the task. On another note, why is everyone downvoting? Are they not reading the whole thing? Do they think I'm posting an actual hiring ad instead of a riddle? Or is this just not as well received as my other themed riddles?

Comment: I can't figure out the downvotes... It seems like a fairly hard, but well thought-out riddle. +1

Comment: "I don't understand" means "this is bad" for some people

Comment: Everyone remember to put full explanations in answers... we are up against it trying to prove we can keep a good standard of quality.

Comment: I like it, Travis!

Comment: I don't understand the prism part - aren't the moving boxes rectangular shaped the entire time?

Comment: They are rectangular prisms, aka three dimensional rectangles, once built taped up.

Comment: @AE You forgot team player. You have to be team player.

Comment: Is "shaped into in prisms" deliberate?

Comment: Yes. Boxes are sold flat and must be built by the purchaser or by movers into the shape suitable for containing household goods. The boxes are shaped from flat to prismatic.

Comment: "Highly triticumized water" is a morsel of wordly genius. Nicely done on that whole segment, in fact.

Comment: Wait, did you jump straight out from the *Little Inferno* universe into the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: Google returns one result for `triticumized` -> This page! Well done on inventing a new word.

Comment: After those downvotes, this is currently the top voted question on Puzzling.SE :D

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I think that you're asking someone to

> help you move.

Reasoning:

The prisms are

> cardboard boxes.

The sine waves are the

> cardboard's corrugation.

You move them twice: once from

> the house to the truck, then back into the new house.

When you're done with

> the boxes, you break them down

so they're rectangles again.  You can store them for later or throw them out.

You will be paid for your help in

> pizza and beer.

Gramineaeze refers to

> Poaceae (aka Gramineae), the family of plants that includes the cereals used in the brewing of beer. Through drenching and allowing the cereals to ferment, magical beer is born!

The other item is

> Pizza, a combination of:
>  | cheese, a milk product that is acidified (soured) and whose proteins are made to coagulate
>  | Sauce/meat/veg, biological life that has been eviscerated (a term whose dictionary definition means the removal of organs, but whose popular definition often refers to the ripping or cutting apart of a living entity in a very brutal or astonishing way).
>  | Dough, a combination of flour (ground grains of the triticum family) and water.

Comment: HA, I was way off. Nicely done.

Comment: Wow! Nice one, Matt and @TravisKindred