# Feedback for a new(?) puzzle format

Tags: visual, puzzle-creation

My wife likes solving puzzles and I like creating them. But I'm afraid my latest idea might not be as great as I thought - could you please beta-test it and give feedback on what to improve and how? Or has this idea been used by others I could learn from? The puzzle would be the image below, without any content or clue (at least initially).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plotting the brightness of three horizontal slices of the image shows the following:

> [image]
>  Mathematica code:
> `ListLinePlot[#,AspectRatio->1/4]&/@ImageData[img][[125;;375;;125,;;,1]]`

It takes a little interpretation, but I think it says something like:

> SHADOWY BLOCKY WORDS

Comments on the puzzle:

> * I pretty much immediately recognized this puzzle as similar to ["Merlin and Hermes: Mysterious Lines" by Tryth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6165/merlin-and-hermes-mysterious-lines) (thanks to [Carmeister in the comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115100/feedback-for-a-new-puzzle-format/115101#comment321711_115101) for finding it!). If I wasn't familiar with it then I probably wouldn't have been able to solve it.
>  * Being able to plot the brightness made it a *lot* easier, trying to solve it without the plot would have been more difficult, but probably more interesting as well.
>  * Due to those facts, the most difficult part was figuring out the letters from their upper profiles. One thing that made this a lot easier was the unique shape of the letters in this font: for example, you can see the leg of the R that makes it distinct from the B, and the lower end of the S makes it distinct from other curved letters like C and O. Choosing a font where the parts of the letters are more aligned would make this part more difficult and, I think, more interesting. Letter sets that could be made confusable are BDPR (half-round tops) CGOQS (round tops) EFITZ (flat tops) MV (deep vees) XY (shallow vees).
>  Two letters that did stump me for a bit were the K, which I thought was an N; and the Y, which I thought was an M for a bit. Then I thought it was an X, which made the letters read "SHADOWXBLOCKXWORDS," which, if I assume X separates words which is something I've seen in cryptography puzzles before, would make the solution "SHADOW BLOCK WORDS," which actually makes sense. Finally I realized that the vee was too high to be an X and could only be Y, which led to the final answer.

Comment: You got it correct, do you have any feedback to give? I too think I saw something similar but wasn't sure if it was here and recently, or somewhere else, or just in my imagination. Oh, and how did you produce these graphs? I clearly need to clean up a few spots... '-.-

Comment: ^^ Ditto - there is one on this site and I've been looking for it but can't remember any key words from the flavourtext in order to pinpoint it!  It was only about 5 or 6 letters long if I remember correctly...

Comment: There definitely was a similar one before, but I too have failed to find it.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You're thinking of [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6165/merlin-and-hermes-mysterious-lines) I think!

Comment: @Carmeister Yes, that was it, thank you :)

Comment: @zovits Rot13: Lbh pna nyjnlf hc lbhe tnzr naq Sbhevre genafsbez vachg oevtugarffrf svefg... Abj, jbhyqa'g vg or sha? ;)

Comment: @Lodinn I'm still unsure whether the current version is the right difficulty, I'm certainly not looking to dial it up even more :D

Comment: Yup, I confirm that I too was thinking of the one Carmeister found. Well done!